# Github - how to keep your forked repo in sync with the original while updating the code

Tags: git

So I am almost at the point of my 1st PR at an open source project. I know how to keep my forked/local repo in sync with the original. But I am contributing to a code since last 1 week and in the meantime, the original repo got ahead with new commits.

So how should I sync my forked/local repo in sync with the original without loosing the changes I made locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your local repo can have more than one remote repo. If you forked a repo on a place like GitHub, and then cloned that locally, you already have one remote, probably called `origin`. What you can do is add a second remote to your local repo, called something like `upstream`:

```
git remote add upstream https://original/repo/url
git fetch upstream
```

Now let's say you've been doing work in a local branch called `my-feature`, and you want to update it with the most recent changes from `master` in the upstream repo.

```
git checkout my-feature
git merge upstream/master
```

Then you resolve any conflicts, commit the merge to your local repo, and push the changes to `origin` like any other commit.