# How to merge master into branch submitted as pull request?

Tags: git, github

Scenario:

- I sent a pull request up that is being reviewed. (1)
- While my pull request was being reviewed, another pull request got merged into master. (2)
- When this happened, the travis builds for my pull request started failing because of the changes in (2).
- (2) has some new files that are not yet present in my pull request

**Question**
How can I get the `master` and merge it into my branch and push the changes to github so that travis builds start again.

Comment: How does Travis build knew about 2 if it was building for 1 ? Travis build for 1 should not be affected by 2. Best solution for your problem - abandon 1, merge master in your branch and raise new PR 3.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53199291/github-how-to-keep-your-forked-repo-in-sync-with-the-original-while-updating-t  I think that might be what you need.

Answer (score 1):

After the other pull request has been approved - which resulted in the changes to be merged into master - you now need to merge master back to you branch and retest your branch.

You can do it via:

1. `git fetch origin master`
2. `git merge origin/master`
3. `git push`

or

1. `git checkout master`
2. `git pull`
3. `git checkout your_branch`
4. `git merge master`
5. `git push`

Comment: I have the original repository (the one I forked) as `upstream`